# CAS Jboss AS7 HTTPS redirect

Tags: jboss, https, cas, jboss7.x

**How is it possible to configure Jasig's CAS to listen only on HTTPS port (8443)?**

We have application divided into two parts, portal and SSO authority ([JASIG CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas)). Both are running on JBoss AS7 and different machines. Portal and SSO authority are configured to redirect from HTTP (8080) port to HTTPS (8443) port by

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0" default-virtual-server="default-host">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="http" scheme="http" redirect-port="8443"/>
    <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="https" scheme="https" secure="true">
        <ssl name="https" password="pass" certificate-key-file="/path_to_keystore.jks"/>
    </connector>
    <virtual-server name="default-host">
        <alias name="myapp.domain.com"/>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
...
<socket-binding name="http" port="8080" fixed-port="true" interface="public"/>
<socket-binding name="https" port="8443" fixed-port="true" interface="public"/>
```

Port redirection works well on portal part, but CAS ignores the redirection and works at http (8080) as well (shows information about non-secured access).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For correct java web app SSL configuration is necessary to make some part of application secured in `web.xml` file. Then redirect works flawless.

```
<security-constraint>
     <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>sso secured pages</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </web-resource-collection>
     <user-data-constraint>
         <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
     </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```